# Ruby Remove several Elements from array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array filled with several dates

```
 arry = ["06-01-2014", "07-04-2014", "14-01-2014"
         "14-04-2014", "16-01-2014" "27-03-2014",
         "30-12-2013", "31-03-2014", "27-02-2014"]
```

I would like to remove element 6 and up Preferably have 2 different arrays.

Is that possible?

Comment: are you looking for `arry[0..5]` and `arry[6..-1]`?

Comment: `arry[5..-1]` works great. thanks add it as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Please add two commas to `arry`.  No reply req'd, as I'll delete this after you've done the edit.  You should always run the code you post to make sure it's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feel free to accept @JanDvorak's answer but you could do this as well

```
arry = ["06-01-2014", "07-04-2014", "14-01-2014","14-04-2014", "16-01-2014", "27-03-2014","30-12-2013", "31-03-2014", "27-02-2014"]
first_five = arry.shift(5)
#=> ["06-01-2014", "07-04-2014", "14-01-2014", "14-04-2014", "16-01-2014"]
arry 
#=> ["27-03-2014","30-12-2013", "31-03-2014", "27-02-2014"]
```

or non-destructively (maintaining `arry`)

```
arry = ["06-01-2014", "07-04-2014", "14-01-2014","14-04-2014", "16-01-2014", "27-03-2014","30-12-2013", "31-03-2014", "27-02-2014"]
first_five,rest = arry.partition.with_index{|a,i| i < 5}
first_five
#=> ["06-01-2014", "07-04-2014", "14-01-2014", "14-04-2014", "16-01-2014"]
rest
#=> ["27-03-2014","30-12-2013", "31-03-2014", "27-02-2014"]
arry
#=> ["06-01-2014", "07-04-2014", "14-01-2014", "14-04-2014", "16-01-2014","27-03-2014", "30-12-2013", "31-03-2014", "27-02-2014"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to delete using index

```
arry.delete_at(5)
```

and as @Jan Dvorak mentioned you can split them based on index positions using

```
arry[0..5] and arry[5..-1]
```

Comment: What's the point of deleting before slicing?  All it does is change `arry`, which may not be desired.

Comment: `delete_at(index)` will remove a single element at that index you could use `delete_if.with_index` and choose what indexes to delete in a block

Answer (score 0):

Here's another (non-destructive) way, but nothing could be simpler and clearer than what @Jan suggested.

```
arr = ["06-01-2014", "07-04-2014", "14-01-2014",
       "14-04-2014", "16-01-2014", "27-03-2014",
       "30-12-2013", "31-03-2014", "27-02-2014"]

[arr.first(5), arr.drop(5)]
  #=> [["06-01-2014", "07-04-2014", "14-01-2014", "14-04-2014", "16-01-2014"],
  #    ["27-03-2014", "30-12-2013", "31-03-2014", "27-02-2014"]]
```

Comment: not that it matters I just think it looks reads nicer to use `take` instead of `first` when used with `drop` also it should be `[arr.first(5),arr.drop(5)]` otherwise you are losing an element.

Comment: @engineersmnky, thanks for the correction.  (I had misread the question as, in effect, partition on the 6th element.)  As for `take` instead of `first`, I'm indifferent.  You could argue that the word `take` suggests `remove` (but we could say the same about `drop`), whereas `first` does not.

Comment: I agree but the same argument could be made for `drop` either way I love to see how many ways you can skin a cat in ruby :)